# Looping Through while adding the elements from array in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I am just starting out in assembly language, my task was to loop through and array and add each number than display it, however i can not seem to get it to work. I trying to understand what i am doing wrong if any one can explain.

```
this is my code
    .data

    num WORD 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 6

    .code
    main PROC

    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, 0


   mov eax, OFFSET num + TYPE num   
   mov ecx, [LENGTHOF num]  
   Lp:
      mov ebx, [ecx * TYPE num]
      add eax, ebx
   loop Lp

   exit 

   main ENDP

   END main
```

Comment: You should explain (i.e. comment) your code so we can tell what you want each instruction to do. Then you can even use a debugger to compare what the machine does. That said, it's unclear why you do `mov eax, offset num + type num`, you forget to add the base address when indexing and you of course don't print anything.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at example for fasm windows which works (prints 31 in console) and hope you'll get something useful from it

```
include 'win32wxp.inc'

    .data

Num dd 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 6
Buf db 16 dup (?)
Dum rd 1

    .code
Start:
    lea esi,[Num]
    mov ecx,LENGTHOF Num
    sub edx,edx
Lp: lodsd
    add edx,eax
    loop Lp

    invoke  wsprintf, addr Buf, '%d', edx
    invoke  AllocConsole
    invoke  WriteConsole,<invoke GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE>,Buf,<invoke lstrlen,addr Buf>,Dum,0
    invoke  Sleep,-1
.end Start
```

Comment: This will loop too many times: iteration-count (ECX) = size in bytes, instead of count in elements.  Since this is MASM, you could actually use `mov ecx, LENGTHOF Num` instead of `mov ecx, (Buf-Num)/4`

Comment: fixed, thanks @PeterCordes